# How to remove space between header and next div element in body tag?

Tags: html, css

I tried everything with margin-bottom and margin-top on both header and div class, but nothing happens. I want to remove space between header and next element but to keep white border between them.

Here are part of html and full css:

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 15%;
  border: 4px solid white;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #839F93;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
}
ul {
  padding: 15px;
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: black;
}
header {
  background: #385044;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
h1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
iframe {
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: white 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <img src="picture-of-me.jpg" alt="Picture of Ivan">
    <h1>Ivan's site</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="vangelis-chariots">
    <h2>Vangelis - Chariots of fire</h2>
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TYJzcUvS_NU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <p>Click to play video and listen to music</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
header ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

[see here](http://jsfiddle.net/vefwo0Lh/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot that :) I am beginner.

Comment: What's the difference if I set margin to 0 with header ul and what with just ul?

Comment: Each block elements has it's weidth, height, margins and padding. The height of element is the height of its contents plus paddings. If you have list that has some bottom margin set then header element will extend it's height so whole ul element (with margin) fits inside it. Take a look at css box model http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model

Answer (score 1):

Just add `margin:0;` to the `ul` in the header which will override the default top/bottom margin that is applied to `ul`s.

```
ul {
  margin:0;
  padding: 15px;
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(255,255,255, .5);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64m12bLf/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the margin from the `<ul>`:

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 15%;
  border: 4px solid white;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #839F93;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
}
ul {
  padding: 15px;
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: black;
}
header {
  background: #385044;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
h1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
iframe {
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: white 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="picture-of-me.jpg" alt="Picture of Ivan">
  <h1>Ivan's site</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
<div class="vangelis-chariots">
  <h2>Vangelis - Chariots of fire</h2>
  <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TYJzcUvS_NU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <p>Click to play video and listen to music</p>
</div>
```